# On which mobiles would intel app sdk / meego run?

Tags: iphone, ipad, windows-phone-7, mobile

http://appdeveloper.intel.com/en-us

MeeGo* is an exciting new open source mobile OS that promotes innovation and portability across multiple mobile device types, such as tablets, netbooks and smartphone.

If it is an OS it means it will not run on iPhone/iPad nor Android nor Windows phone 7 nor wndows 7 so it's again yet another mobile platform to cope with ?

It's not clear also if intel app sdk = meego ?

Answer (score 1):

According to  http://appdeveloper.intel.com/en-us/sdk

> "The Intel AppUp™ Software Development
>   Kit (SDK) [is] for native Windows* and
>   native MeeGo* application development"

It is therefore not the same as Meego.

In terms of devices which run Meego, see http://wiki.meego.com/Devices